# Clang: How can I tell whether size of constant size array declaration is a macro expansion

Tags: clang, c-preprocessor, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

I'm working on a clang-tidy checker to spot some problematic idioms in a large codebase.  I need to look at constant-size arrays declared in structs, and determine whether the size was given as an integer literal, or if the size results from a macro expansion.

For example, in this code:

```
#define ARRSZ 392

typedef struct Foo {
  int  a;
  int  litsz[392];
  int  macsz[ARRSZ];
} Foo;
```

Both of the fields `litsz` and `macsz` have the same size (392).  However, my checker needs to treat them differently.  In the AST, of course, after preprocessing is done, these FieldDecls appear identical in every respect.   Somehow, I have to use the preprocessor to distinguish these.

One way I'm pretty sure would work is to register a preprocessor callback, and cache the SourceLocation for every macro expansion that occurs.  Then, when I'm looking at the fields, I can get the SourceLocation of the size Expr, and try to find that location in my cache of macro expansions.  If I find the location, it's a macro expansion, and if I don't, it's not.   While I think I could get that to work, it seems horribly inefficient.

I tried doing this without building a cache of all macro expansions, by getting the SourceLocation of the size Expr, and then calling `Preprocessor::isAtStartOfMacroExpansion()`. But that triggers an assertion for `litsz` -- apparently, one can only use that method of the Preprocessor if you already know you have a Macro.  Same with `Preprocessor::getImmediateMacroName()`...

How can I do this efficiently?  (And, ideally, simply...)